# Best choice structure for MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to decide on what will be more efficient between two different systems for MySQL to handle my data. I can either,

1: Create around 200 tables, each having around 30 rows & 5 columns.

2: Create 1 table, having around 6000 rows & 5 columns.

I am using Laravel for this project and Eloquent will be handling this. Does anybody have any opinions on this matter? I appreciate any/all responses.

Comment: Please explain more. What is your use case what will the tables store etc.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2.

For such low row counts the overhead both in terms of programming effort and computation of joining 200(!) tables far outweighs the "flat file" approach.  Additionally, MySQL will attempt to cache the entire 6000-row table in RAM, assuming you're not storing massive BLOBs.